# Can a mere change of variable make any physical difference?

Tags: coordinate-systems, correlation-functions

As far as I am aware, a change of variable is intended to transforms a problem into an equivalent and usually simpler problem. But I came across an expression in a statistics class which seems to violate this understanding. Most likely I am missing something. I couldn't identify what I am missing.

The expression I came across is $$\int_0^t\int _0^tds ds' < \Delta(s-s').\Delta(0)>$$ where $< \Delta(s-s').\Delta(0)>$ is the correlational function for the random variable $\Delta(s)$ . By a change of variable $s'' =s-s'$, the double integral can be written as a single integral $$∫^t_0∫^t_0dsds′<Δ(s−s′).Δ(0)>=2∫^t_0(t−s′′)<Δ(s′′).Δ(0)>ds′′ $$

The lecturer then choose an exponential form for the correlation function $$<Δ(s−s′).Δ(0)>=<Δ(s′′).Δ(0)>=e^{−(s−s′)/s_c}$$

Now if we substitute this correlation functions into the integrals, either before changing variables or after changing variables, we should be getting the same result. But I didn't find this to be the case when I tried verifying the equivalence.

Here is what I tried. $$∫^t_0∫^t_0dsds′<Δ(s−s′).Δ(0)> = ∫^t_0∫^t_0dsds′e^{−(s−s′)/s_c}$$
$$=2s_c^2 (\cosh(t/s_c)-1)$$     On the other hand, $$2∫^t_0(t−s′′)<Δ(s′′).Δ(0)>ds′= 2∫^t_0(t−s′′)e^{-s''/s_c}ds′′$$ $$=2[ts_c- s_c^{2}+s_ce^{-t/s_c}]$$
Obviously $$2[ts_c- s_c^{2}+s_ce^{-t/s_c}] \neq 2s_c^2 (\cosh(t/s_c)-1)$$

Is there any hidden assumption that I am missing?

Comment: I'd double check your double integral, that's not what I get. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+e%5E%28-%28x-y%29%2Fa%29+dx+dy+ I strongly disagree with the second part of this statement: "a change of variable transforms a problem into an equivalent and usually simpler problem." Almost every change of variables makes the problem more complicated. It is only very special and well-motivated changes of variables that really do simplify things, and you should always check you know *why* things are simpler, because it's easy to do a change of variables incorrectly and fool yourself.

Comment: I have edited the question to : "a change of variable is intended to transforms a problem into an equivalent and usually simpler problem"

Comment: It seems that the equation in my question which equates a double integral to a single integral applies only for even correlation function. So, the choice to use exponential decay correlation function,  in the single integral that results from the change of variable no longer ensures the truth of that equation(where double integral is equated to single integral).

Comment: The auto-correlation should have $|s-s'|$ in the exponent

Comment: Yeah, then the equality would work. Thanks.